# validating HTML fields in form using regex using perl

Tags: regex, perl, validation

I have a couple of quick questions regarding using regex to validate some fields in a form. But I seem to be having some problems.

so here is the code

```
$userNameReg = "[a-zA-Z0-9_]+";
$passwordReg = "([a-zA-Z]*)([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)";
$emailReg = "[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[a-zA-Z]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}";

if ($onLoad !=1)
{
@controlValue = ($userName, $password, $phoneNumber, $email);
@regex = ($userNameReg, $passwordReg, "phoneNumber", $emailReg);
@validated;

for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
{
    $retVal= validatecontrols ($controlValue[$i], $regex[$i]);
    if ($retVal)
    {
        $count++;
    }
    if (!$retVal)
    {
        $validated[$i]="*"
    }           
}

sub validatecontrols  
{       
    $ctrlVal = shift();
    $regexVal = shift();
    if ($ctrlVal =~ /$regexVal/)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if ($ctrlVal !~ /$regexVal/)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

So what happens is that it still validates special characters, and I can't understand why. It does throw a flag if I enter a single special character but if its part of a word in the middle, beginning or end it validates.

Also please disregard the phone number part, because I haven't gotten to that part yet. I still have to create a regex that validates the phone number, digits only, first digit greater than 2.

Thank you all in advance for your help and insight.

Cheers

Comment: You shouldn't try to create your own regexes for things like email address validation; they are notoriously difficult to get right. Use a module like [Email::Valid](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Valid).

Comment: the instructor wants us to create our own regex, as part of the assignment

Comment: You'll need to a couple of `+` in the email regex `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}`

Comment: Your passwords are restricted things of the form aB1, aaBB11, etc. aAa1 won't work, nor will Aa1

Comment: @EssiJoon Fair enough. Keep in mind that `"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com` is a [valid email address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses), although that is probably beyond the scope of your assignment.

Comment: I don't think your regexes will behave at all the way you expect them to. You don't need the parens and you are ordering where numbers and capitals show up in your passwords which I don't think is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're missing start/end anchors. So `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` should be `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$`. This way pattern will only match full string.

Also I strongly recommend you to enable `use strict;`. It can save you from a lot of mistype errors. Just add following to the beginning of the script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

This will force perl to only allow defined variables. In most case you'll need to add `my` to first use of your variables (for example `my $ctrlVal`).

In `validatecontrols` you don't need second `if` statement. You can just return false like this:

```
sub validatecontrols  
{       
    my $ctrlVal = shift();
    my $regexVal = shift();
    if ($ctrlVal =~ /$regexVal/)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: or just `return ($ctrlVal =~ /$regexVal/);`